# Editing Control Buttons of iOS Media Player

Tags: ios, custom-controls, controls, media-player

When a video is played in iPhone (or iPad), the standard buttons appear (play, pause, forward, etc). I want to add buttons along with those default buttons. How can I do that?

Waiting for reply.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You simply can’t.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I have to add a share button, which must be along with the controls(according to the project requirements). How can I do that?

Comment: If you have access the the movie player controller’s `view` property, you can add a custom subview (in your case, a UIButton). But I doubt you'll be able to move the playback-control buttons in order to make room. And even if you manage to do it, they are part of a private view hierarchy, so Apple might refuse your app, or change the view layout in the future, which will break your code.